# RCLCPP ROS2 check if node is already running

Tags: ros2, c++

I have noticed my node can be re-run as a second time. While using python before, this was not a problem, as when you launched the node the second time, it would return an error.

What is the best practice to detect if node is already running, using RCLCPP?

Best Regards,
C.